# load() JSON data, generate HTML table and place it inside of a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I have probably a very simple jQuery question - probably missing a tiny bit.

I have a button which loads data in JSON format from a PHP script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showLastGame(id) {
        $('#top').load('http://preferans.de/cards-json.php?id=' + id + '&limit=1');
}
</script>
```

...

```
Show your last game &raquo;
<input type="button" onclick="showLastGame('DE13370')" value="Show">
```

That works well - I can see the loaded JSON data after the button is clicked.

But I actually would like to pass that loaded data to a JavaScript-function (I'm trying to reuse one from [dataTables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html)), which will construct a return a HTML-table as a String:

```
function renderGame(cardsTable, nTr) {
        var aData   = cardsTable.fnGetData(nTr);
        //console.dir(aData);
        // .... HTML table constructed here....
        return str;
}
```

How to do this please?

And how to put that generated string inside of the `#top` div?

Comment: What are `cardsTable` and `nTr` meant to be and where do they come from?

Comment: Nevermind please - that's my own function - I use it for example at http://preferans.de/DE13370 and would like to reuse it. My question is more: how to put a string inside of `#top`. And how to pass load()ed data to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call rather than `.load()`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/cards-json.php',
    data: {
        id: id,
        limit: 1
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    ...
}).done(function(data) {
    // data is your JSON - use it however you want here
    var topHtml = renderGame(arg1, arg2);
    $('#top').html(topHtml);
});
```

I've assumed the `renderGame` function is the one that returns the HTML content for the `#top` element; if not, then change that to the correct function call.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function renderGame(cardsTable, nTr, html) { // added html to be passed so it can be manipulated further

        // .... HTML table constructed here....
        // using things like `var part = $('selector',HTML_STRING)` you can extract parts
        // to modify, and build a string for the table with them

        var part1 = $('span.menu',html).eq(0) // get the first `span` with class `menu` from the html string passed and store in `part1`
        ... etc ...

        str = "<table><tr><td>" + part1 + "</td></tr></table>" // etc...

        return str;
}
function showLastGame(id) {
    // use `$.get` and a callback function after it got data
    $.get('/cards-json.php?id=' + id + '&limit=1',function(d){
        // d is a string containing the response of the `get` request
        var table = renderGame(???,???) // <~ not sure what variables your function takes
        // set the HTML of the target element
        $('#top').html(table);
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a way to go is to use [jQuery.getJson()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Example, based on you code:

```
function showLastGame(id) {
    $.getJSON('/cards-json.php?id=' + id + '&limit=1', function(data) {
        var html = '<ul>';
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            // Whatever you what to do, eg.
            html = html + '<li>' + key + ': ' + val + '</li'>);
        });
        html = html + '</ul>';
        $('#top').html(html);
    });
}
```